# What is the name of the command ./ in linux?

Tags: linux, process, command, cpu, kill

I am using the following script obtained from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90155/how-can-i-automatically-kill-the-process-with-the-highest-cpu-load) to kill processes with high CPU usage:

```
#!/bin/bash

# tries to kill process with highest CPU load
# (if it is part of a specified list of troublemakers)

TROUBLEMAKERS="java Rscript"


sleep 1 # wait a few seconds (just as a precaution)

TOPPROCESS=$(top -b -n 1 | sed 1,6d | sed -n 2p)
TOPPID=$(echo "$TOPPROCESS" | awk '{print $1}')
TOPNAME=$(echo "$TOPPROCESS" | awk '{print $12}')

if [[ "$TROUBLEMAKERS" == *"$TOPNAME"* ]]
  then
      echo "Cause of high CPU load: "$TOPNAME" ("$TOPPID")"
      echo "In troublemaker list. Killing..."
      kill -9 $TOPPID
  else
      echo "Cause of high CPU load: "$TOPNAME" ("$TOPPID")"
      echo "Not in troublemaker list. Exiting..."
      exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

As can be seen, `TROUBLEMAKERS` contains a list of processes that might cause high CPU load. For example if I execute the command `java myfile` and this command hogs the CPU, it will be killed.

Now if I execute `./anotherfile`, what is the process name I need to put in `TROUBLEMAKERS` that will make commands containing `./` with high CPU usage to be terminated?

Putting `TROUBLEMAKERS="java Rscript ./"` does not work.

Comment: `./` isn't a command, it's just a path to a directory (try `ls -ld ./`) and basically equivalent to `$PWD/`. If you're in `/home/me`, then `./` refers to `/home/me` and `./anotherfile` refers to `/home/me/anotherfile`. People write `./file` because it's the shortest way to refer to a file in the current directory when you want to execute a specific file instead of a command in your $PATH.

Comment: @thatotherguy +1 for `./` is not a command

Answer (score 0):

you could try, `kill -9 < pid# >` , that usually kills a proccess no matter what variables.

Comment: thats if i even remotely understand your situation XD

Comment: This command is already in the script. I need to way to get list of pid that have been launched by `./` Is there an alternative way of running a script other than `./myscript`?

Comment: no unless you just tried to use kill 0 to ping, then delete it after its reconised.